# How to find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$ using complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, holomorphic-functions

Consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$. How to find its value using complex analysis?

I am considering $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n^2}$. It is absolutely convergent in $|z|<1$. So it is holomorphic and can be differentiated termwisely, namely $f'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n-1}}{n}$, thus $zf'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n} = \log (1-z)$ where $\log$ takes principal branch such that $\log1=0$. Thus we have
$$
f'(z) = \frac{\log (1-z)}{z}
$$
I cannot proceed now. Is it possible to use complex analysis theories to tackle this?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Well, it's a standard application of the Weierstrass Factorization Theorem that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}={\pi^2\over 6},$ and from there you can easily evaluate this sum.

Comment: Your $f(z)$ is called the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function).

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you and I heard this result. I learned in calculus when studying Fourier analysis. But is there any way to start from what I did? Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here: [Evaluating the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/620071/144766)

Comment: @mechanodroid Thank you so much!

Comment: @saulspatz By the way, any reference of the application of Weierstrass Factorization theorem to get $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$?

Comment: I don't have a book to look in.  I'm sure you find it in Alfohrs, or Knopp.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you!